# How can I make the full button clickable and not just the text? SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, button, text, swiftui

```
Button("Login") {
        authenticateUser(username: username, password: password)
    }
    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
    .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
    .background(Color.blue)
    .cornerRadius(10)
                    
NavigationLink(destination: HomeView(), isActive: $showingLoginScreen) {
    EmptyView()     
}
```

I am new to coding and have no clue how to fix this. I have to click on the text in order for the button to be activated.

Answer (score 0):

this is one way, make sure to read the apple documentation, check the different initializers there are for the button and other things.

```
Button {
  authenticateUser(username: username, password: password)
} label: {
  Text("Login")
      .foregroundColor(Color.black)
      .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
      .background(Color.blue)
      .cornerRadius(10)
}
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isTapped = false

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            isTapped.toggle()
        } label: {
            Text("Login")
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                .background(isTapped ? Color.blue : Color.green)
                .cornerRadius(10)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I have found to do this is to put your button’s code in as an argument to the “action:” parameter of the Button initializer, then set the Button’s Text inside the button. Then use  a frame modifier to make the button the size you want. The Spacers() around the Text are important to make the button expand to fill the frame and make the whole area clickable.

```
Button(action: { authenticateUser(username: username, password: password) }) {
        Spacer()
        Text(“Login”)
        Spacer()                   
 }.foregroundColor(Color.black)
      .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
      .background(Color.blue)
      .cornerRadius(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, Text can be used.

```
Text("Login")
    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
    .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
    .background(Color.blue)
    .cornerRadius(10)
    .onTapGesture {
        authenticateUser(username: username, password: password)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)`:

```swift
Button {
    runLogin()
} label: {
    Text("Login")
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .font(.title3)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center) // this line expands the clickable area
}
.foregroundColor(Color.black)
.frame(width: 300, height: 50)
.background(Color.blue)
.cornerRadius(10)
```